# Android. Функция с настройками

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment, android-shared-preferences

Как создать функцию в которую бы передавали настройки. Например у нас есть MainActivity в ней есть фрагмент. Есть кнопка по которой мы переходим в диалоговый фрагмент настроек где мы заполняем какую нибудь информацию (сколько лет, рождение и тому подобное).
Как написать функцию, которая бы запоминала все заполненные поля и в следующий раз, когда мы опять нажмем на это кнопку, то оставались бы те же настройки.

P.S. Есть Активити, Фрагмент настроек(кнопка в тулбаре) и Фрагмент(всегда показывается в Активити)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте SharedPreferences

Записываем:

```
String name = ...;
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
pref.edit().putString("name", name).apply();
```

Считываем:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String name = pref.getString("name", "");
```

Т.е. в момент записи вы сохраните ваши данные, а при показе фрагмента вы можете достать их и отобразить

Comment: а куда он их сохраняет?

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, во внутреннюю папку приложения, в xml-файл  `sharedpreferences.xml`

Comment: получается "name" - метка, а name - то что надо записать?

Comment: и еще, почему второй аргумент пустой? `pref.getString("name", "");`

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, инфа хранится парами  ключ-значение. Первый агрумент в обих случаях ключ. Второй - в первом случае то значение, кое вы хотите записать, т.е. имя пользователя, напрмиер, взятое из поля ввода. Во втором случае, второй аргумент, пустая строка, это значение по умолчанию которое будет возвращено если в фале не будет пары ключ-значение

Comment: Спасибо. благодарю!